# pipenv cannot find module 'runpy' when installing dependancies

Tags: windows, path, environment-variables, pipenv

```
C:\Users\danie01\fox\test\robotframework>pipenv install
Installing dependencies from Pipfile.lock (49d163)...
An error occurred while installing robotframework-seleniumlibrary==3.1.0! Will try again.
An error occurred while installing selenium==3.9.0! Will try again.
An error occurred while installing robotframework==3.0.2! Will try again.
An error occurred while installing psutil==5.4.3! Will try again.
  ================================ 4/4 - 00:00:00
Installing initially failed dependencies...
     -------------------------------- 0/4 - 00:00:00
Could not import runpy module
ImportError: No module named 'runpy'

     ================================ 0/4 - 00:00:00
```

I recently reinstalled Python for all users, and now I am having this problem when attempting to run `pipenv install`. Why might this be?

Python 3.5 is in path. Running immediately after the prior command:

```
C:\Users\danie01\fox\test\robotframework>echo %PATH%
C:\Program Files\Python 3.5\;C:\Program Files\Python 3.5\Scripts\;blahblah

C:\Users\danie01\fox\test\robotframework>pipenv run python --version
Python 3.5.0
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue recently when moving from 3.5 to 3.7.3:

- I removed 3.5, installed 3.7.3
- remove older versions of python from `path`
- updated pipfile to point to newer version of python
- restarted terminal
- reinstall pip: https://www.liquidweb.com/kb/install-pip-windows/
- reinstall `pip install pipenv`

Then you should be good to run `pipenv install`.

Comment: Hi there,

I have been searching a solution for this similr issue almost from past 4 hrs now. But some how I could not find a resolution for the same issue that I am facing obn ubuntu.
could someone please help.

TIA!